# The message: "Fail! Play Again" does not display when score < 3

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I am new in iOS-Swift, The message: "Fail! Play Again" does not display when `score < 3`.

```
func discussScore(sender: AnyObject){       
  // after asking all questions, if score >=20, the player accesses stage 2
    if (questionField.text == listOfQuestions[4]) {
          if (score >= 3) {
              //go to next step
          }

          if (score < 3) {
              alertMessageWrong("Fail! Play Again") // (here's my problem)
          }                    
     }
}

func alertMessageWrong(theMessage2: String) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: " ", message:theMessage2, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:theMessage2, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: The second `if` is just the opposite from the first one, I recommend that you use an `else` instead, that way you are sure that one or the other block of code will be executed.

Comment: @cjnevin I did it previously ({code}if (questionField.text == listOfQuestions[4]){code} ) but my algorithm is too thicky, so I decide to create a func discussScore(). When I compile all work perfectly except the alert message that doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd put a breakpoint at this line:

```
if (questionField.text == listOfQuestions[4])
```

and step through each line to see which route gets taken... You can see how to debug [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/debugging/).

To check if you've hit the right question, you might be better using a 'step' integer rather than comparing strings. Incrementing this integer on after each question is answered. Then you could check if you're on the last question doing:

```
if currentStep >= listOfQuestions.count { ... }
```

Secondly, the code would be cleaner if you did:

```
let minimumScore = 3
if score < minimumScore { 
    showAlert()
    return
}
// go to next step.
```

Comment: @cjnevin-Dan Beaulieu-NiñoScript   There is an alert message already that displays either the answer is wrong or not. Do you think it's the reason why my 2nd alert message ("Fail! Play Again") does not display?

Comment: This could also be causing the problem, do you see a warning in the console?

Comment: I checked, but No warning.

Comment: Did you breakpoint your code? Put a print where your alert should show and see if you see that in your console.